# How to respond to a concern regarding telephone interview?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, phone

Let's say that an employer has requested and arranged for a telephone interview based on an online profile you set up via a job search platform, online.

You ticked the "available for phone interview" box, but no calls have been received or recorded. Each month, you check for the phone records to match them up with the phone interview requests. They don't add up!

The phone record shows that no calls came through from any of the companies that emailed you back with concerns over their not being able to contact you.

Should you ignore their concerns or reply to their inquiries?

Comment: I'd guess they were too lazy to phone you and preferred email contact instead, and use a little creative white lies to justify it...

Comment: That or they were just trying to get your email address and contact info to add you to a list...

Comment: This doesn't feel like a Workplace issue. Are you getting *any* calls originating from that job search platform? If not, check that your number is correct (remember your country code if it's international), and take it up with the platform if it is. If you are getting calls occasionally, ask those that didn't get through which number they used and figure it out from there.

Comment: Echoing @dukeling's comment. I have had several occasions where my mobile provider has failed to deliver both phone calls **and** voicemails. Can't explain why - people tell me they've called, heard my personalized outgoing message, left a message, and I never got it or a record of a missed call. It's happened much less frequently since I turned all my voicemail handling over to Google Voice.

Comment: "Let's say that..." sounds like a hypothetical situation.

Answer (score 3):

First things first:

BE PROActive if it starts to get messy and having problems you should eliminate all noise. A good tactic will be contact the employer and recruiter. E.G

"Hi xxxx I am available for phone interview but never have received any call"

And the second and most fundamental is to think as your employer. E.G

If your employer is from US give your number to call FROM US. Like

- [your country code] [area code] [phone number]

Test it using google voice or another voip service from us.

Avoid all "noise" in this process real noise and this communication noise.
At the phone interview make sure your are in a quiet room where you can concentrate and talk freely.

Hope that helps and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty hard to tell who's at fault here: it could be that the employer or recruiter isn't being quite honest, or perhaps your phone or the job platform has some technical problem.

I'd suggest that next time you have a query like this, ask the person contacting you a a favour, explaining that you're worried there might be a technical issue you need to rule out. Ask them to call you at an agreed time when you are ready, and email you if you don't answer. If you don't get the call, but they assert that they called you.... you'll need to look into a technical issue somewhere.